# Standard error of sample proportion problem on a test - can't figure out what I did wrong

Tags: standard-error, proportion

Here's a problem from a recent stats test that i got wrong.  Can't figure out why my answer is wrong:  "According to national data released by the US govt in 2015, 25% of car accidents in the US are associated with texting and driving. A recent random sample of 275 accidents is taken and as a result, 29.8% were the result of texting and driving.  A) Determine the mean of the sampling distribution of the proportion of all us Accidents  B) determine the standard error.

I got the mean correct with .25, but I got .0276 for the standard error, which is apparently not correct. I'm using the formula sq rt(p(1-p)/n).  Any help on what I'm doing wrong is appreciated!

Comment: Did you use 0.298 for p or 0.25?

Comment: I used 0.298.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous commenter asked if I used .298 or .25 as P.  I wasn't able to respond to the comment (i assume because I am new to this forum and don't have enough experience points), but his comment made me realize that .298 is p, not P.  The formula for standard error requires P, the population proportion.  Thanks for pointing me toward the answer!

Comment: If you think this is the answer to your question, you can accept it by clicking the check mark below the vote total to its left.

Comment: @Mike if you're logged into your account you always have the privilege to comment in your own posts. Not sure what difficulty you experienced.

Comment: When I try to accept the answer it tells me I have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: As short as it was maybe my comment should have been an answer.  I am glad I helped.